# c++11: call virtual base-class method using a central command-mapper

Tags: c++, c++11

I'd like to make a command Mapper that accepts commands of a certain type and hands them over to runtime-registered members of various sub-classes of a common `Bindable` class.

As the sub-class members are of different types, I struggle with programming a working `Mapper` class. How do I need to implement it to make it work?

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <functional>   // std::bind
#include <map>          // std::map
#include <vector>       // std::vector

struct Command {
    int cmdNum;
    int numArgs;
    std::vector<int> args;
};

struct Invocation {
    enum Source {
        SOURCE_X = 0, SOURCE_Y, SOURCE_Z,
        SOURCE_END
    };
    Source src;
    Command cmd;
};

struct Bindable {
    virtual void handleCmd(Command Cmd) = 0;
};

struct A : Bindable {
    void handleCmd (Command cmd) {
        std::cout << "called handler-method of class A" <<std::endl;
        std::cout << "cmdNum: " << cmd.cmdNum <<std::endl;
    }
};

struct B : Bindable {
    void handleCmd (Command cmd) {
        std::cout << "called handler-method of class B" <<std::endl;
        std::cout << "cmdNum: " << cmd.cmdNum <<std::endl;
    }
};
```

The problematic Mapper:

```
struct Mapper {
    void bindCmd(Command cmd, Bindable* mBindable) {
        //Fill a multimap with cmd.cmdNum as keys and mBindable as values
    }

    //Send cmd to each registered Bindable for the respective cmdNum
    void handleInv(Invocation inv) {
        auto mMatches = mBinds.equal_range(inv.cmd.cmdNum);

        for(auto mMatch : mMatches) {
            mMatch.second()->handleCmd(inv.cmd);
        }
    }

private:
    std::multimap<int, Bindable*> mBinds;
};
```

The desired usage shall be:

```
int main() {
    A a;
    B b;

    Command cmdA = {200, 4, {1,2,3,4}};
    Command cmdB = {400, 3, {3,2,1}};
    Command cmdC = {600, 2, {8,9}};

    Invocation invA = {Invocation::SOURCE_X, cmdA};
    Invocation invB = {Invocation::SOURCE_Z, cmdB};
    Invocation invC = {Invocation::SOURCE_Z, cmdC};

    Mapper mMapper;

    //Register Commands
    mMapper.bindCmd(cmdA, &a);
    mMapper.bindCmd(cmdB, &a);
    mMapper.bindCmd(cmdA, &b);
    mMapper.bindCmd(cmdC, &b);

    //React to incoming Invocations
    mMapper.handleInv(invA); //Call handleCmd of a and b
    mMapper.handleInv(invB); //Call handleCmd of a
    mMapper.handleInv(invC); //Call handleCmd of b
}
```

Comment: *"I struggle with programming a working Mapper class"* Do you have any *specific* problems or a general issue with the design of such a class?

Comment: specifically I dont know how to make the multimap accept functions of different sub-classes without statically knowing which sub-class-types will be registered at run-time.

Comment: [Here's a running version of your example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39129b703ad2e6c2) I just fixed some minor bugs.

Comment: The [`std::function` wrapper](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) is often used for run-time binding of unknown types.

Comment: Wow, that was closer than I thought! Thank you! Could you briefly explain, what you did with the "pair_range" struct?

Comment: The range-based for loop requires on the right-hand side of the `:` something that can provide the `begin` and `end` of a range. It searches for member functions or free functions with the name `begin` and `end` for that purpose. `multimap::equal_range` returns a `pair`, which has members `first` and `second`. So we need to translate `first`->`begin` and `second`->`end`. (The way I solved it is just a hack, though.)

Comment: Ok, thank you! I'd like to accept your solution if you post it below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in the OP works, as far as I can see, when two minor bugs are fixed:

```
std::multimap<int, Bindable*> mBinds;

void handleInv(Invocation inv) {
    auto mMatches = mBinds.equal_range(inv.cmd.cmdNum);

    for(auto mMatch : mMatches) {            // 1
        mMatch.second()->handleCmd(inv.cmd); // 2
    }
}
```

---

### 1

`std::multimap<K,V>::equal_range` returns a `std::pair` of iterators, where the member `first` specifies the begin, and the member `second` the end of an iterator-range.

The range-based for loop expects on the right-hand side of the `:` something that can provide the begin and end of an iterator-range, but searches for free functions or member functions with the names `begin` and `end`. Therefore, we have to translate `std::pair::first` -> `begin()` and `std::pair::second` -> `end()`.

There are of course library solutions for this (e.g. [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/iterator_range.html)). A minimal solution could be:

```
template<typename It>
struct iterator_pair_range
{
    It b;
    It e;

    It begin() const { return b; }
    It end() const { return e; }
};

template<typename It>
auto make_iterator_pair_range(std::pair<It, It> const& p)
    -> iterator_pair_range<It>
{ return {p.first, p.second}; }

for(auto mMatch : make_iterator_pair_range(mMatches)) {
```

---

### 2

```
mMatch.second()->handleCmd(inv.cmd); // 2
```

The member `second` of `std::pair` is a public data member, not a member function:

```
mMatch.second->handleCmd(inv.cmd); // 2
```

---

I'll suggest you post your code on [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com), since there are more general, safer (e.g. lifetime issues) and possibly easier solutions to this general problem. For example, there is the [boost.signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/signals2.html) library; also there is the [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) wrapper that allows storing objects of arbitrary type, as long as they can be called with a certain signature.

Comment: Thank you! I should definitely have a look at boost... As this is intended to run on an embedded system (ARM Cortex M4) I shied boost for ressource-reasons - until now.